# How to fix Sync Browser not working on ICS

Tags: sync, accounts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I just got a Galaxy Nexus and all is good apart from that my Sync Browser doesn't work.  When I run logcat against it it gives me the error of :

```
BookmarksSync  I  Sync failed due to soft error: Skipping any commits.
```

I've seen some pages online which describe this issue and suggest fixing by removing all your bookmarks and starting again, but I'd rather not do this. *see edit below

Does anyone know how I can fix this without removing all my existing browser setup?  <strike>or if this is the only way, can someone point me to a page with clear instructions.</strike>

** EDIT **
I tried removing all my bookmarks and syncing and it's still giving me an error with no bookmarks present.

Comment: Have added a bug report to the Android issue tracker.  If you are experiencing the same, could you please star it : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disable syncing in Google Chrome.
2. Remove stored sync data on your [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard).
3. Enable sync again in Google Chrome making sure that only the passwords are encrypted.
4. Disable and enable sync browser in ICS.

There is a more detailed howto with photos on my [blog](http://blog.abrah.am/2011/12/sync-is-currently-experiencing-problems.html) if you need it.

Comment: Yup from the comments on the Android issue tracker it seems that encrypting everything is the issue here - in order to have browser sync, you need to have unencrypted data in chrome sync.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Eventually, I disabled the following:

auto fill forms; sync via USB an developer tools. It worked!

Oh also I cleared data (settings..content settings) for Google sites.